# Como recuperar el registro acabado de insertar en MySql con C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

Estoy haciendo un programa en el cual varias computadoras insertan datos a una base de datos en un pequeño servidor, el problema que tengo es que quiero recuperar el registro que se acaba de ingresar.

No me sirve saber "el ultimo" registro por que si otra computadora ingresa unos momentos despues un registro, puede que la consulta no alcance a mostrarlo sino que muestre el que se hizo unos momentos despues, la forma en la que ingreso mis datos es la siguiente

```
string instruccion = "INSERT INTO pedido(id_cliente_Cliente, importe_Pedido, piezas_Solicitadas) VALUES ('" + IdClienteTxt.Text + "', '" + TotalTxt.Text + "', '" + TotalPiezasTxt.Text + "')";
        conexion.Open();
        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(instruccion, conexion);
        try
        {
            if (comando.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Datos Insertados");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        conexion.Close();
```

La clave primaria es un autoincremental numerico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y basicamente ese valor es el que necesito, no se si haya alguna forma de que la misma instruccion del insert te devuelva los valores agregados, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: A simple vista se me ocurren tres soluciones rapidas. 1) Que en tu programa localmente guarde el ultimo registro en una variable y que esta se vaya actualizando cada vez que esa maquina haga un insert 2) Poner algun campo en tu BD por ej Id_maquina en donde al hacer un insert guardes que maquina ha hecho el insert y luego hacer una query en funcion de dicha maquina.3) Hacer unos triggers que se ejecuten al insertar y creen un archivo de logs donde puedas tener mas informacion  no solo la de tu tabla y a si dejar la de pedidos intacta. Seguro que a alguien se le ocurre alguna forma interesante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que voy a comentar es que debes usar parametros siempre, concatener los valores en un string no es una buena practica

```
try
{
    conexion.Open();

    string instruccion = @"INSERT INTO pedido(id_cliente_Cliente, importe_Pedido, piezas_Solicitadas) 
                            VALUES (?idcliente, ?importe, ?totalpiezas)";

    MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(instruccion, conexion);
    comando.Paramters.AddWithValue("?idcliente", IdClienteTxt.Text);
    comando.Paramters.AddWithValue("?importe", TotalTxt.Text);
    comando.Paramters.AddWithValue("?totalpiezas", TotalPiezasTxt.Text);

    int rowafectadas = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if(rowafectadas > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Datos Insertados");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }

    conexion.Close();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Ahora bien, para obtener el ultimo registro necesitas del id para poder realizar un SELECT usando este en el WHERE

```
    string instruccion = @"INSERT INTO pedido(id_cliente_Cliente, importe_Pedido, piezas_Solicitadas) 
                            VALUES (?idcliente, ?importe, ?totalpiezas);
                            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";

    MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(instruccion, conexion);
    comando.Paramters.AddWithValue("?idcliente", IdClienteTxt.Text);
    comando.Paramters.AddWithValue("?importe", TotalTxt.Text);
    comando.Paramters.AddWithValue("?totalpiezas", TotalPiezasTxt.Text);

    int LastId = Convert.ToInt32(comando.ExecuteScalar());
```

veras como se adiciona el

```
 SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

y se usa el

```
comando.ExecuteScalar()
```

para obtener el valor del id que se acaba de crear

Solo queda usar este en una consulta como ser

```
SELECT * FROM pedido WHERE IdPedido = ?lastId
```

Answer (score 1):

Agrégale a tu consulta un `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`

> ...Este valor no puede verse afectado por otros clientes

Te dejo el enlace de la documentación: [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)